# Problemas de reconhecimento do primefaces responsive mobile

Tags: primefaces, mobile, layout-responsivo, grid

Erro em reconhecer PrimeFaces responsive mobile.

Estou usando o PrimeFaces 5.3 e a funcionalidade [Grid CSS](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/grid.xhtml)  funciona perfeitamente no Desktop, como visto nas imagens abaixo.

Maximizado
[image: Maximizado]

Restaurado
[image: Restaurado]

Mas infelizmente no mobile não esta funcionando, pois ele fica com a visão do desktop Maximizado.

Mobile
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém teria uma dica de como resolver este problema?

Comment: alguém já passou por isso?

Comment: foi apenas colocar o código 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
que funcionou...